# Curly braces in C-shell variable

Tags: curl, csh

This is really driving me nuts. I am trying to store a command in c shell variable and then executing it with eval. But I always get missing "}"

```bash
set temp="curl  -v --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:65000/foo/bar/load'  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'  --data-raw '{ "modelType": "john", "resource": "doe" }'"
eval $temp
```

Please help.

Comment: The "shell" tag is for POSIX-compliant shells. csh is its own thing, so the "csh" tag should be used there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I used it, but it is showing the same error even after that.

Comment: My note was about how to write the question on this site, not about how to fix your problem / how to write your code.

Answer (score 0):

The shell offers two characters for strings: single quotes (') and double quotes ("). The difference is that using single quotes prevents any interpretation of the content inside the string (e. g. variables) and using double quotes allows it. If you mix both, make sure to properly escape the string.

An easy way to prevent errors is to either use single or double quotes inside the string. But you should not mix both. Here are some examples:

```
echo '"' # correct
echo ''' # incorrect
echo "'" # correct
echo """ # incorrect
```

To solve the issue change your string to:

```
set temp = 'echo -v --location --request POST "http://127.0.0.1:65000/foo/bar/load" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw "{ "modelType": "john", "resource": "doe" }"'
```

Double quotes are used inside the string and the string is surrounded by single quotes.

If you pass the created variable to a command, make sure to use quotes. In this case, the variable is interpreted as a single argument. Your code should look like this:

```
eval "$temp"
```

Please consider that eval is a dangerous command.

For further information I highly recommend the book *Using csh & tcsh* by Paul DuBois. It is a good reference for the C-Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes inside double quotes should be escaped with `"\""`; variables set with `set` are better with the equal sign separated from the variable name and content; to prevent braces' special meaning, `eval` should be issued within double quotes:

```
set temp = "curl -v --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:65000/foo/bar/load' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{ "\""modelType"\"": "\""john"\"", "\""resource"\"": "\""doe"\"" }'"
eval "$temp"
```

If you don't want to use `eval`, you can have an alias to source the variable from a FIFO:

```
mkfifo ~/qscr
alias qscr '( echo "$temp" > ~/qscr & ) ; source ~/qscr'
```

To properly execute multi-line variables, the `:q` modifier must be applied:

```
eval "$temp:q"
alias qscr '( echo "$temp:q" > ~/qscr & ) ; source ~/qscr'
```

It's much better to have it in an alias, though:

```
alias temp "curl -v --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:65000/foo/bar/load' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{ "\""modelType"\"": "\""john"\"", "\""resource"\"": "\""doe"\"" }'"
```